# How to anchor a custom item/layout on a BottomAppBar instead of a floating action button?

Tags: android, xml

I want to anchor a custom item/layout/element on a BottomAppBar instead of a floating action button. For example, anchoring a relative Layout that contains multiple buttons.
here is my code.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationAppView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="but1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="but2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**I want the output to be something like this**
[image]

Comment: The layout you want is purely custom and cannot be achieved through the current one which is designed to accommodate a circular fab. The option you've is to create a custom layout and draw a custom curve using Bezier curve or you can use an image asset. Check [this](https://medium.com/swlh/curved-cut-out-bottom-navigation-with-animation-in-android-c630c867958c) example, this can surely help.

Comment: Thanks that's what exactly I'm looking for.